# Fragment display issue in tablet container android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on a tablet with android version 7.0, I'm having a display issue while clicking on the listview cell of the first fragment (on the left side) to display the information details on the second fragment (on the right side). It takes at least 5 seconds to display. There are many views that are gone. I have been stuck for the last couple of days and I couldn't fix it.

[image]

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/section1"
            layout="@layout/layout_section1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/section2"
            layout="@layout/layout_section2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_section1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/section3"
            layout="@layout/layout_section3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_section2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/section3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/section"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_guide"
                android:text="@string/guide"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/section"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_modif"
                android:text="@string/modifier"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/section"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_delete"
                android:text="@string/supprimer"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_edit_validate_cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/section3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/validate_button"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/register_button_bg"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/validate_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/register_button_bg"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/cancel_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_pwd_validate_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.example.ui.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/validation_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:maxWidth="300dp"
                android:text="@string/validation_message"
                android:textSize="16dp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_border"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="right|center"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/validate_button"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/register_button_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/validate_button"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.example.ui.KeyboardViewNumber
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/keyboard_color"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/push_keyboard_btn"
    android:keyTextColor="#000000"
    android:keyTextSize="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:shadowRadius="0.0"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: from where you are getting the details ?

Comment: Currently i'm displaying the details with static values, the problem is not from the java code, and also i don't have java code implemented i'm just using xml. I don't know why it takes all that time to display the second fragment.

Comment: you are using high resolution image ?

Comment: i already tried to remove all the images but it still the same problem

Comment: Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, and the best way to resolve my problem is to use only Relative Layouts. The Linear Layouts caused me lots of problems when rendring.